# What is the best way to go through your script once more?

Tags: vbscript

I have a script which copies some files from some folders to another. I'm checking with a if condition if the folders exists and if they don't exist the script goes to else and creates the required folders. 
What's the best way to copy the files without restarting the script once more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Else:

```
If Not FolderExists(Src) Then
   need Src!
   Quit
End If
If Not FolderExists(Dest) Then
   CreateFolder Dest
End If
Copy
```